Getting this error in oracle 19c ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
I have created user in oracle 19c and grant privileges, but i am not able to login using that user getting logon denied error.
I have logged from command prompt  sqlplus / as sysdba
then i created user
create user "c##keyan" identified by "keyan123";

i grant the following privileges
    grant connect to "c##keyan";
    grant dba to "c##keyan";
    grant resource to "c##keyan";
    grant create session  to "c##keyan";


my listener.ora
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = H:\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME =  H:\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
    )
  )


my tnsnames.ora
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

after this i exit from the sql prompt and again
login from the command prompt  sqlplus c##keyan/keyan123@//localhost:1521/orcl
I am getting this error
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Did i missed something? Please advice.

Remove the quotation marks from the username to avoid creating a case sensitive username. Case sensitive passwords are fine, but case sensitive usernames create several problems.
If you really need a case sensitive username, you must always use it with quotation marks. And on Windows, you need to escape those quotation marks and log in like this:
sqlplus \"c##keyan\"/keyan123@orcl

Also, are you sure you want to use the CDB instead of the PDB? You likely want to do almost all of your work inside a PDB instead of a CDB. (Or re-install with the "traditional" architecture and avoid all this unnecessary multitenant complexity.)

Thanks for the response, I tried the same in PDB created user and grant everything but still logon denied error is coming, also i gave as you posted the string sqlplus "c##keyan"/keyan123@orcl to connect database it's also failed. To install oracle 19c non pluggable version how to do that please adivce

@Keyan Can you edit your question with you updated script and error messages? For example, what happens when you remove the double quotes. Also, I wonder if you even have the multi-tenant architecture - it seems weird that your tnsnames.ora file only includes one entry. Run select cdb from v$database to see which architecture you have. I recommend installing using the Oracle Database Configuration Assistant GUI. That program should take care of all the setup and files for you. To get the non-pluggable version, uncheck the check box "Create as a Container database" on the "Creation Mode" tab.

To create nonCDB database, when running "dbca", on second screen(Creation Mode) uncheck "Create as Container database".

Thanks for the response, yes its getting complicated any how i don't need multi tenant database as you said i unchecked the check box for non pluggable version and installed it now its works as usual.

Username has '##', so I think you didn't aware that is multitenant container database(cdb).
You have to specify container(s) when you create user and access rights, either when connecting to db.
Oracle Doc

thanks for the response i followed the refer document but still i am getting the same error   SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = orclpdb                                                                        SQL> create user "keyan" identified by "keyan123"  CONTAINER=CURRENT;
User created.
SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION TO "keyan" CONTAINER=CURRENT;
Grant succeeded.
SQL> grant PDB_DBA to "keyan";
Grant succeeded.
SQL> connect keyan/keyan123@orclpdb
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I tried all the steps in the document you attached but still getting the same error. i worked oracle 9i,10g,11g but didn't get such errors. in 19c its different  so anything i am missing even tried chatGPT didn't nail out
